# JSON not deserializing as expected?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a collection of classes set out like this:

```
public class Xml
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string encoding { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public string Expires { get; set; }
    public string MaxArrivalScope { get; set; }
}

public class Trip
{
    public string ETA { get; set; }
    public string TripNo { get; set; }
    public string WheelchairAccess { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Trip> Trip { get; set; }
}

public class Route
{
    public string RouteNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Destination Destination { get; set; }
}

public class Platform
{
    public string PlatformTag { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Route Route { get; set; }
}

public class JPRoutePositionET
{
    public string xmlns { get; set; }
    public string xsi { get; set; }
    public string schemaLocation { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public Platform Platform { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Xml xml { get; set; }
    public JPRoutePositionET JPRoutePositionET { get; set; }
}
```

}

I have JSON like this:

```
{
  "xml": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "JPRoutePositionET": {
    "xmlns": "urn:connexionz-co-nz:jp",
    "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "schemaLocation": "urn:connexionz-co-nz:jp JourneyPlanner.xsd",
    "Content": {
      "Expires": "2017-04-09T15:59:31+12:00",
      "MaxArrivalScope": "60"
    },
    "Platform": {
      "PlatformTag": "2628",
      "Name": "Awatea Rd near Awatea Gdns",
      "Route": {
        "RouteNo": "125",
        "Name": "Redwood/Westlake",
        "Destination": {
          "Name": "Westlake & Halswell",
          "Trip": [
            {
              "ETA": "4",
              "TripNo": "4751",
              "WheelchairAccess": "true"
            },
            {
              "ETA": "32",
              "TripNo": "4752",
              "WheelchairAccess": "true"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why is Newtonsoft not parsing correctly to the `Platform` class? It returns `null`. Will I need to format the JSON to cut out all the other information I don't want? Or is it something I am missing?

Comment: I'm not sure this works: `public List<Trip> Trip`. Try with `public Trip[] Trip`

Comment: You're objects are nested in the json object.  You need to pull the objects out in order they are given and deserialize to the proper class.  Could you post the portion of code that is deserializing?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I am using NewtonSoft to deserialize to List<T> so it should work like that.

Comment: This line: `var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);` will return correctly initialized `result.JPRoutePositionET.Platform`. Show your deserialization code or check that deserialized json is correct one

Comment: @Fabio provide correct answer... I just tested and works fine.

Comment: Oh I am an idiot. I think I should just delete my whole program. When I was Deserializing I was doing <Platform> not RootObject. Welp. Clean up lads, I am just having a down moment.

Comment: But now when I get JSON like https://pastebin.com/pebp178s I can't seem to use Json2CSharp to get the classes I'd need as it doesn't make Destination a List.

Answer (score 0):

Fabio's Comment of

`var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(js‌​onString);`

Worked.

But now when I get JSON like pastebin.com/pebp178s I can't seem to use Json2CSharp to get the classes I'd need as it doesn't make Destination a List, it also changes Trip to an Object instead of a class. Which is really weird. It just throws an error saying the JSON can't be parsed.